# R - Subsetting XTS via Time and Which

Tags: r, date, subset, xts

Currently, I have an `xts` time series, called `Data`, which contains a `Date`, and two value columns, `Value1` and `Value2` which are both numbers. I would like to get a single number as output from my code which would be the mean of `Value1` in the time period from a point where `Value2 < mean(Value2)` and going forward 14 data points, weeks in this particular data set.

In order to get the dates where `Value2 < mean(Value2)`, I wrote the below code

```
Data[which(Data$Value2 < mean(Data$Value2)),"Date"]
```

However, I am not sure how to get the mean of `Value1` in the period, going 14 days forward from each of the resultant dates from the above code.

Example Dataset:

```
                Value1  Value2
1   2009-01-02  22.6500 17
2   2009-01-09  21.4700 56
3   2009-01-16  20.6100 -50
4   2009-01-23  19.6800 13
5   2009-01-30  19.2800 172
6   2009-02-06  20.1300 -120
7   2009-02-13  18.9900 17
```

The mean of Value2 is 12.57. Therefore the selected dates would be 2009-01-16 and 2009-02-06 since Value2 < mean(Value2) there. I would then like the mean of Value1 in the time period from 2009-01-16 to 2009-01-30 and from 2009-02-06 to 2009-02-20, in matrix form with the start date followed by the mean(Value1).

Comment: Do you want to calculate the mean of `Value1` in the original data or in the subsetted data, where all `Value2` are less than `mean(Value2)`?

Comment: In the subsetted data

Comment: xts objects store the date/times in the `index` attribute and do not have a `"Date"` column (unless you purposefully create one yourself). Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Comment: Sorry, I did mean the index attribute. Will add example momentarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you were asking for. It will calculate the mean of `Value1` in the subsetted data. Note however, that it is not clear what you want to do in the cases where there are less than 14 more days ahead. I include two versions of the `my.func` definition, one will produce `NA`s in the final output, the other wont. You can check this out yourself. Also, if I understood the question correct, it is not necessary to use `xts` for this task (so I dont use it in my example).

```
set.seed(99)
Data <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-03-30"), by = 1), 
               Value1 = rnorm(90), 
               Value2 = runif(90))

strt <- which(Data$Value2 < mean(Data$Value2))

subData <- Data[which(Data$Value2 < mean(Data$Value2)),]

my.func <- function(x) mean(subData$Value1[x:(x+14)])       #will produce 14 NA

#my.func <- function(x) mean(subData$Value1[x:(x+14)], na.rm = TRUE)   #wont produce NA

sapply(seq_along(strt), my.func)
```